# How to refresh route or component in react without reload page after update data from database?

Tags: reactjs, react-component

i am update my data from database like delete or change to updated data. now page is need to reload to see my data in current component. how i can see my updated data without reload my website .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely looking for a "push" mechanism. They can take the form of publish/subscribe technologies like WebSockets, or ones that emulate them like [Long polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling), interval polling (repeated web requests to the HTTP server).

Depending on your framework, you'll likely be using [WebSockets API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) ("WS") to send a signal from the server. They're often used for 'push events' by web developers, an example of how it works:

1. The backend server will run a WS server
2. The client's browser will connect to WS when they load their page, "subscribing"
3. The backend server "publishes" / "emits" / "pushes" messages

   e.g. `"STORE_UPDATED"` with an object of updated properties, e.g. `{"apples": 2}` of updated properties

   What this looks like depends on if you're using WebSockets API directly or a higher level wrapper.

   For an idea see [Writing WebSocket client applications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications) on MDN.

   In your case with React, [react-use-websocket](https://github.com/robtaussig/react-use-websocket) and its [sandbox demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-otkczd?file=index.js) may be of service.
4. The client handles them. In your case, your react component would update its local state or a higher level component will place them into child props for them to be updated.

Where you proceed next depends on your backend technology:

- Cloud-based: Google's [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/)
- Python: [Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) for django, [Flask-SocketIO](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for Flask.
- Node.JS: [Socket.IO](https://socket.io/)
- For more WS libraries / frameworks across languages: [awesome-websockets](https://github.com/facundofarias/awesome-websockets)